# How to have duplicate display on ubuntu 14.04 with gnome

Tags: 14.04, gnome, display

I have ubuntu 14.04 wtih GNOME shell I am unable to have duplicate display.
In my display setting I just can extend or disable or enable one display but there is't any duplicate option in display setting.
So how can I have duplicate screen in both my device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check off "mirror displays" in the System settings, under 'displays'. Then click apply. Here's a picture of the menu in Unity (which is based off of Gnome 3, has identical system settings and 'displays' menu):

[image: Screen configuration panel screenshot]

Comment: There is no mirror displays option on my Ubuntu

Answer (score 12):

Once the second screen is attached use the following shortcut keys Super-key (or Windows-Key) + P. Each time its pressed you will cycle between

- Extended display
- Duplicate display
- display attached screen/projector only
- native (laptop/desktop) screen only