# Activate screen mirroring by using keyboard input

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I recently broke my laptop screen , how do make the screen display on an external monitor by just using keyboard shortcuts , I’m using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with absolutely no gui modification’s

Comment: It depends on the hardware but its usually Fn and F1 or F3 which cycles through external monitor only and both or none.

Comment: There is usually a symbol on the F key to show which one.

Comment: Super+P try 1st) hold Super then press n release p key  try 2nd) hold Super then press p twice 3rd n 4th with 3 times n 4 times.. at one level out of 4..you can see pic on your second monitor..  https://askubuntu.com/a/699855/739431