# How to Duplicate Displays on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I have my laptop and Two monitors. I just want to use my two monitors as two separate displays, and don't care about my laptop. Under Settings -> Displays, when I select Join Display, I would have my laptop as display1 and two monitors as display2, so I can not use two monitors as two separate displays. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> You can try with Settings -> Devices -> Displays
> Change Display Mode - Single Display
> and select the monitor you want

Comment: I wan to use two monitors as two separate displays, so this doesn't work!

Comment: No one in Ubuntu community doesn't solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Once the second screen is attached use the following shortcut keys Super-key (or Windows-Key) + P. Each time its pressed you will cycle between

- Extended display
- Duplicate display
- display attached screen/projector only
- native (laptop/desktop) screen only

Stolen from [How to have duplicate display on ubuntu 14.04 with gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697018/how-to-have-duplicate-display-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-gnome)